# want to export dynamic multi-flat file from SQL table column field

Tags: sql, ssis

I need to import data from some text files, and then I need to export the data back out to a text file again. 
I using SSIS 2013.

I'm taking the data from a text file and inserting into my DB. Then some transformations are run on that data. Finally I need to export the data back out to a text file with the same name as the imported file name.

My table is TEMP_MIG 
Filename is like that

```
ORDERTYPE CHANNEL TEAMNAME PRDCODE QTY FILENAME   
------------------------------------------------
ZOR       01      TEAMA    1100001 2   TEAMA.TXT
ZOR       01      TEAMA    1100003 5   TEAMA.TXT
ZOR       01      TEAMA    1100005 3   TEAMA.TXT
ZOR       02      TEAMB    11002   2   TEAMB.TXT
ZOR       01      TEAMC    11002   1   TEAMC.TXT
ZOR       01      TEAMC    11003   2   TEAMC.TXT
```

I would like to export that stored data, grouped by the `FILENAME`, using the `FILENAME` as the file name.

TEXT FILE FORMAT -

```
TEAMA.TXT 

ZOR       01      TEAMA    1100001 2   
                           1100003 5   
                           1100005 3   

TEAMB.TXT

ZOR       02      TEAMB    11002   2


TEAMC.TXT

ZOR       01      TEAMC    11002   1                              
                           11003   2
```

How do I export the data to multiple file names from SQL?

I'm getting this error: `Error: 0xC020200E at Data Flow Task, Flat File Destination [2]: Cannot open the datafile "C:\Users\test". Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E`

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: @digital.aaron when I tried, system cannot generated the file multiple. Can you guide me?

Comment: Error is like that ...

Error: 0xC020200E at Data Flow Task, Flat File Destination [2]: Cannot open the datafile "C:\Users\test".
Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.

Comment: Is your Flat File Destination just `C:\Users\test`, like that? Or is it missing the file name, like `C:\Users\test\TEAMB.TXT` for example? That error is saying that it can't find or open the destination file. So either it doesn't exist (or the path is bad), or the SSIS user agent doesn't have access to it.

Comment: Now, I see the error now. Thank for your help.